# Tips for following git commits?

Tags: git

I need to follow two separate projects via git that I do not have intimate knowledge of.

I know I can read the git log to see the diffs then look at the files before and after, but I'm curious:

Does anyone have any tools or tips to make it much easier to read/watch changes happening to a project via git? Just seeing diffs of files really isn't enough.

Comment: Not sure it is relevant in this case, but by far the easiest way to track git projects is to host it on github, or to setup your own gitlab server http://gitlab.org/

Answer (score 1):

Hosted git solutions with web frontends greatly simplify the watching process. If these projects are already hosted on something like github or gitlab, configure some notifications via RSS/email. I tend to check the network graph frequently, it's a great tool, especially the one in GitLab. Browsing projects through the web interfaces is generally enough for me.

If you want to stick to the command line, the `git log` command actually has a lot of useful options which tend to be overlooked, from what I've observed. To get a good grasp of what it can do it's best to refer directly to the [**git log manpage**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html). Some things which might help you "watch" a certain project:

One line per commit,

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Since a certain amount of time (say, since the last time you checked)

```
git log --since="2 days ago"
```

Filter by  author. You don't have to spell out the whole author, just enough to uniquely identify him and git matches it:

```
git log --author=<parts of the name or email>
```

Print out in a custom format (below: hash | when | author - message)

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h | %ad | %an - %s" --date=relative
```

That, + `gitk --all` or equivalent is already quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments above.

It seems like no one tool will solve this yet. What I had in mind was a kind of simple text editor where you can browse the source tree at once and click forward/back through the various commits and branches and see the lines added/removed graphically. The comments above help achieve that but not in a one-stop shop.

For anybody else curious, I did find http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-exploring-the-history-of-a-git-repository/, which looks great for vim users. It lets you step forward/backward through git commits while looking at the file, though in a large file, it's still up to you to spot the changes.